# What in-game content comes with the Collector's Edition of Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What in-game content (maps, weapons, skins, missions, etc.) comes with the Collector's Edition of Mass Effect 3 that the basic package does not include?

Comment: -1 - Just because I feel that collector's edition are almost always rip-offs.

Comment: [I'm normally the most outspoken advocate of judicious and widespread downvote use here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4157/3129), but @MarkRogers, that has to be the worst reason to downvote a contribution to this site that I've ever seen.

Comment: -1 Becuase it took longer to type the question into gaming.se than it would have to type it in google

Comment: @Stephen Now *that* is a good reason to downvote! And it isn't even one that I personally [would have bothered to explain.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4157/3129)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the release notes on the Origin purchase page:

- Four weapons: N7 Eagle, N7 Hurricane, N7 Crusader, N7 Valiant
- A Robotic Dog: A faithful sidekick to keep you company on board the Normandy.
- New outfits for Ashley, Kaidan, James Vega, and Liara T'Soni.
- N7 Hoodie: Outfit item for Shepard while onboard the Normandy.
- From Ashes: An additional downloadable mission and character.

Comment: The zero day DLC is $10 separately, so that's already halfway to the difference in cost between the standard and collector's editions!

Comment: @Shinrai That makes me feel much better about having pre-ordered the collector's edition instead of the standard edition when I really shouldn't be spending money at all! Now if only I'd splurged a little more for faster shipping I might be playing already...

Comment: NB: The dog will not follow you around, it just wanders around the shuttle bay (though you can walk up to him sometimes and tell him he is a good dog). Also, I have been digging the Valiant sniper rifle on my infiltrator, so I'm glad I got the CE if only for that gun. Ridiculous, I know.